# Can I configure a dynamic table name in my Azure Function output binding?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using an HTTP triggered Azure Function written in JavaScript(model V3).
I have an output binding that writes to the table storage like this:

```
{
  "tableName": "SomeTable",
  "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
  "name": "tableBinding",
  "type": "table",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

My question is if it's possible to make `tableName`  dynamic value. For example, I'd like to pass a table name with my HTTP request, and make this function write to that table. I wasn't able to find related documentation, and I'd appreciate if you could point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to pass the table name in HTTP request in the following way-

**index.js-**

```
module.exports  =  async  function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

if (req.params  &&  req.params.tableName) {
const  tableName  =  req.params.tableName;
context.bindings.tableBinding  = {
PartitionKey:  'Orders',
RowKey:  '123'
}

context.res  = {
status:  200,
body:  `Writing to table: ${tableName}`
};

} else {
context.res  = {
status:  400,
body:  "Please provide a tableName in the request."
};
}
}
```

**function.json-**

I am passing the table name in `"route": "tables/{tableName}"`

```
{
"bindings": [
{
"authLevel": "anonymous",
"type": "httpTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"name": "req",
"methods": [
"get",
"post"
],
"route": "tables/{tableName}"
},
{
"type": "http",
"direction": "out",
"name": "res"
},
{
"type": "table",
"direction": "out",
"name": "tableBinding",
"tableName": "{tableName}",
"connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting"
}
]
}
```

**Output-**

[image]

[image]

[image]